strong-weak lower semicontinuous of a variational integral
I am considering a variational integral
\begin{align}
I(u,v):=\int_{0}^{T}L(u,v)dt
\end{align}
where $L:L^{2}(\Omega)\times L^{2}(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a proper, lower semicontinuous functional. Moreover, 
$\bullet$ the mapping $u\mapsto L(u,v)$ is continuous for all $v$,
$\bullet$ the mapping $v\mapsto L(u,v)$ is convex for all $u$.
Now, my problem is that I have a sequence $(u_{k},v_{k})$ such that $u_{k}\to u$ strongly in $L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(\Omega))$ and $v_{k}\to v$ weakly in $L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(\Omega))$, then do I have
\begin{align}
I(u,v)\leq\liminf_{k\to\infty}I(u_{k},v_{k}).
\end{align}
My thought is that if I assume $u\mapsto L(u,v)$ is also convex then I immediately have the joint convexity. Hence, with the lower semicontinuity and Fatou's Lemma, I have $I$ is lower semicontinous and then weakly lower semicontinuous with the help of convexity. But since now I only have "partial" convex, so I really have no idea how to deal with this.

Yes, the semicontinuity still holds.
To see this, we consider the problem first for fixed $v$. Then we have by Fatou's Lemma, using that $u \mapsto L(u,v)$ is continuous and a strongly-$L^2$-converging sequence has a subsequence converging pointwise a.e.:
$$0 = \int_\Omega \liminf_{k \to \infty}(L(u_k,v) - L(u,v)) \le \liminf_{k \to \infty} \int_\Omega L(u_k,v) - \int_\Omega L(u,v)$$
This shows $\liminf_{k \to \infty} I(u_k,v) \ge I(u,v)$.
If on the other hand, we keep $u$ fixed and try to prove $\liminf_{k \to \infty} I(u,v_k) \ge I(u,v)$ this boils down to Fatou's Lemma to prove lower semicontinuity and then using convexity to prove weak lower semicontinuity (e.g. with the help of Mazur's Lemma) as you wrote yourself. Therefore, we have
$$\liminf_{k \to \infty} \liminf_{l \to \infty} I(u_k,v_l) \ge I(u,v) \quad \text{and} \quad \liminf_{l \to \infty} \liminf_{k \to \infty} I(u_k,v_l) \ge I(u,v)$$
since we can argue for the two inputs one by one.
Now having $\liminf_{k \to \infty} (\dots) \ge I(u,v)$ means, that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $k_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that the expression in (...) is $\ge I(u,v) -\epsilon$ for all $k\ge k_0$. This means that for sufficiently large $k$ we have
$$\liminf_{l \to \infty} I(u_k, v_l)\ge I(u,v)-\epsilon.$$
Repeating the same argument for the second $\liminf$, we obtain (potentially increasing $k$), that for sufficiently large indices we have
$$I(u_k,v_k) \ge I(u,v)-2 \epsilon$$
for all sufficiently large $k$. Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary we infer $\liminf_{k \to \infty} I(u_k,v_k) \ge I(u,v)$.

Thanks for your answer. So from your proof, I think the lower semicontinuous assumption can actually be reduced to "partial" version i.e. for all fixed $u$, the mapping $v\mapsto L(u,v)$ is lower semicontinous instead of my original assumption.

and maybe irrelavent, I also think we can actually prove a integral form $I(u,v)$ like here is lsc if and only if $u\mapsto L(u,v)$ and $v\mapsto L(u,v)$ are lsc.

Nice proof! one remark: Fatou lemma needs non-negativity (or an integrable lower bound)
